# How to add shadow at a corner of Imagebackground in react-native

Tags: react-native, imagebackground

I'm need to add shadow at the corner of the `ImageBackground` as in WhatsApp to display star.
[image]

how can this be achieved in react-native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Linear Gradient](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient).
Add Linear Gradient as last child of ImageBackground.
Styles

```
{
position: 'absolute',
bottom:0,
right:0,
...otherstyles}
```

And you can add star and text component inside Linear Gradient as its child

```
<LinearGradient [props]>
 ...star
</LinearGradient>
```